# Pandas.apply returning none value on spacy doc column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy

I'm running the following on my pandas df 'sp500news3', it returns a None value

```
def extract_ticker(title):
    for word in title:
        if word in constituents['Symbol']:
            return word

sp500news3['tickers'] = sp500news3['title'].apply(extract_ticker)

#sp500news3 sample:



  index date_publish    title   tickers
0   79944   2007-01-29 19:08:35 (MSFT, Vista, corporate, sales, go, very, well) None
1   181781  2007-12-14 19:39:06 (WMB, No, Anglican, consensus, on, Episcopal, Church)   None
2   213175  2008-01-22 11:17:19 (CSX, quarterly, profit, rises) None
3   93554   2008-01-22 18:52:56 (C, says, 30, bln, capital, helps, exceed, target)  None
```

constituents['Symbol']: sample

```
0      TWX  
1      C  
2      MSFT  
3      WMB ...
```

Replicate spacy doc from the following:

```
constituents =  pd.DataFrame({"Symbol":["TWX","C","MSFT","WMB"]})

sp500news3 = pd.DataFrame({"title":["MSFT Vista corporate sales go very well","WMB No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church","CSX quarterly profit rises",'C says 30 bln capital helps exceed target','TWX plans cable spinoff']})

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sp500news3['title'] = sp500news3['title'].apply(nlp)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? None of the strings in `constituents` seems to be in your titles.

Comment: What dtype is title? is it a string or a tuple? Presumably MSFT is in constituents and that is expected result for the first?

Comment: constituents is longer than sample - contains all sp500 tickers - expecting tickers to be extracted from each title and added to ticker column in `sp500news3` df

Comment: the dtype  of title is a `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `word.text` since when [iterating over a `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#iter) it iterates over [`Token` which doesn't implement `__eq__` for strings](https://spacy.io/api/token):

```
for word in title:
    if word.text in constituents['Symbol'].values:
        return word
```

---

With your example:

```
In [11]: sp500news3['title'].apply(extract_ticker)
Out[11]:
0    MSFT
1     WMB
2    None
3       C
4     TWX
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Comment: I suppose it's not that "doesn't implement `__eq__` for strings:" but that pandas doesn't special case its `__eq__` like it does for strings.

Comment: this still returns none values, have checked `constituents` dtype which is `str`

Comment: @W.R constituents is string but title isn't (you said it was Doc). Please share an example that we can replicate this on.

Comment: Have added the df before sending to spacy doc and code for spacy doc

Comment: have added `constituents` df

Comment: @W.R fixed. you must also use .values (Series contains by default looks in the index rather than the values)